# How to load environment by arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I don't know how to pass the argument to a PropertySource annotation , so I have the following code in the SpringBootApplication , this code load the direction of a Properties Files through arguments.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ProjectApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static String PROPERTIES = null;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Application started with command-line arguments: {}", Arrays.toString(args.getSourceArgs()));
        logger.info("NonOptionArgs: {}", args.getNonOptionArgs().get(0));
        String prueba = args.getNonOptionArgs().get(0);
        String[] parts = prueba.split("=");
        String part2 = parts[1];
        if (OSHelp.isLinux()==true) {
            PROPERTIES = OSHelp.getUserHome()+"/PROPERTIES/"+part2+".properties";
        }else{
            PROPERTIES = OSHelp.getUserHome()+"\\PROPERTIES\\"+part2+".properties";
        }

    }
```

I have the following Hibernate Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:"+{ProjectApplication.PROPERTIES})
public class HibernateConfiguration {
}
```

How can I call the property PROPERTIES of ProjectApplication ?

Now I have the following problem

```
@PropertySource(value = {"C:/Users/Usuario/PROPERTIES/DESARROLLO.properties"})
```

I have the following URL at my HibernateConfiguration file and says that doesn't exist when the file is created !

I don't know why it's happen!

DESARROLLO = DEV

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use profile like dev, prod

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("dev")
public class HibernateConfiguration {

}
```

Or you can use `application-{profile}.properties` for configuration and pass active profile as a command.

Comment: I couldn't use this solution , I have my properties out of the project.

Comment: Then pass the config file as vm argument using --spring.config.location=<file name>

Comment: Hello @Debopam , I have my properties files out of the project by burocracry I think that I can't use this solution my properties files are on the Desktop , I updated the question.